# What is wrong with my integral calculation involving Gauss' law?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the surface $$S=\{(x,y,z)|(x+1)^2+(y+5)^2+(z-4)^2=4\}$$ we want to calculate the flux of the field $$\vec F=-3x^2\hat i-5y^2\hat j+3z^2\hat k$$ through $S$, in the direction going from the point $(-1,-5, 4)$ out of the surface.

Guass' law is $$\oint_S\vec F\cdot\hat n dS=\int_V\vec\nabla\cdot\vec F dV$$

I therefore got $$\oint_S\vec F\cdot\hat n dS=\int_V\vec\nabla\cdot\vec F dV=\iiint_V(-6x-10y+6z)dxdydz$$

To solve this, I changed to spherical coordinates:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=r\cos\theta\sin\phi-1\\ 
y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi-5\\ 
z=r\cos\phi+4
\end{matrix}\right.$

I changed the variables in the integral accordingly, let $\theta$ run from $0$ to $2\pi$, $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and $r$ from $0$ to $2$, and multiply by the Jacobian $r^2\sin\phi$.

$$\iiint_V(-6x-10y+6z)dxdydz=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2}(-6(r\cos\theta\sin\phi-1)-10(r\sin\theta\sin\phi-5)+6(r\cos\phi+4))r^2\sin\phi drd\theta d\phi$$

The answer I got was $64\pi$, but apparently it is wrong.
Did I make a mistake along the way?

Comment: I evaluated your last integral with Mathematica and got $2560\pi/3$.

Comment: You are right. I put the parenthesis wrong in wolfram, so it gave me the wrong answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: So the question is dumb, but I will leave it here as an example for students learning Gauss' law